# Compatible heart rate sensors for CC-RD420DW

Tags: bike-computer, heart-rate

I purchased a bike computer about a couple of months back; which is a Cateye CC-RD420DW. Now this computer is supposed to provide a cadence and a heart rate monitoring, but the heart rate sensor is sold separately (i.e. Cateye HR-10).

Now I've looked for this heart rate sensor, but it's just too expensive. It costs almost as much as the computer bundled with the cadence sensor itself. Which brings me to My question:

Are there other generic compatible sensors that can work with My computer?

I have a Timex and a Polar heart rate monitor.

Is it possible to configure a different sensor to work with the computer?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cateye uses proprietary sensors, so I'm afraid that generic ANT+ sensors won't work.  Although it's possible someone has made a copycat sensor that works with Cateye, I doubt it.

Comment: That's bad news. I guess that's why the prices on the sensor won't go down even on ebay. I'll just use my timex in tandem with the bike computer. I just can't fathom shelling out 60 bucks for a sensor that I though was included, since I already have a heart rate monitor anyways. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pretty blatant money grab to use proprietary sensors when widely compatible ones already exist.  It's the reason I'll never buy another Cateye product myself.